# How to rewrite url with Angular in IIS?

Tags: angular, iis

I have a website in IIS which has two application and as main website an Angular App.

[image]

one of the applications is the API beck-end, the second one is a vanilla javascript app.

To reach vanilla JS application i'm have to make a call to `www.example.com/v/{code}` which will rewrite the `/v/` url to `/api/v/` which return a PermanentRedirect 301 to `/vmenu/` or better the JS Application.

The issue with Angular app hosted at root level is my rewrite rule is ignored and my request to `/v/` is not rewrited in `/api/v/` so i'm not redirected to my JS application but i'm just stuck in Angular one...

it's looks like this:

[image]

While instead of this the request should be processed and the user redirected to `/vmenu/`..

I've tryed the following rewrite rules but it has no effect..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Rewrite VMenu" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="v/(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="api/{R:0}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
        <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(v)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        
        
        
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If it could be usefull here is my Angular routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '*', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  {
    path: ':piva/:negozio',
    component: NegozioComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ModuliComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'location',
        component: LocationComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'asporto',
        component: ProductsComponent,
        canActivate: [ItemsGuardService],
        resolve: {
          menu: ProductsResolver,
        },
      },
      {
        path: 'takeaway',
        component: ProductsComponent,
        resolve: {
          menu: ProductsResolver,
        },
      },
      {
        path: 'ecom',
        component: ProductsComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'item/:id',
        component: ItemComponent,
        resolve: {
          plu: ItemResolver,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  { path: 'cart', component: CartComponent },
  {
    path: 'checkout',
    component: CheckoutComponent,
    canActivate: [CheckoutGuardService],
  },
  {
    path: 'success',
    component: SuccessComponent,
    canActivate: [SuccessGuardService],
  },
];
```

By using IIS rewrite tracing, i just doesn't even process the `/v/{code}` request but the first request is the request to Angular path ':piva/:negozio', which makes a call to `api/profilo`.

Comment: I have created a test demo on my side and It seems your url rewrite rule is working at my side. I suggest you could try to enable the fail request tracing to troubelshoot url rewrite rule to check what has happened. More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules).

Comment: @BrandoZhang hi Brando, which version of IIS are you using? and how's your application pool?

Comment: IIS 10 and I used default iis application pool identity.

Comment: @BrandoZhang i've just set the tracing but it doesn't even catch the request to `/v/{key}` but directly process the request to API made by path in Angular...

Comment: Could you please tell me where you put the url rewrite rule in the visualodar or api or else ?

Comment: @BrandoZhang i've found the issue, i had the @angular/pwa installed and the ServiceWorker was overwritting the IIS Rules so after removing PWA support and ServiceWorker from my angular app the IIS Rules returned to work properly